# Calendar wrong date depends on start day of the week

Tags: tkinter, calendar

If I run this code I got the wrong date and the wrong calendar, if I select the first day as Monday I get the right calendar.
Can someone please help me with this? the code was working fine till last week.
If I print the year, month, and day I'm getting the right result.

```
  from tkinter import *
  from tkcalendar import *
  import time

  root= Tk()
  Y= int (time.strftime('%Y'))
  M= int(time.strftime('%m'))
  D= int(time.strftime("%d"))

  cal= Calendar(root, year=Y, month=M, day=D,firstweekday='sunday', selectmode='none)
  cal.grid(row=1, column=0)
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think it is a bug of `tkcalendar` module.

Comment: @ ace1668 I don't think so, it was working fine for a few months. till Jan 8th. I read something about iso week and it related to 52 w/y or 53 w/y

Comment: There is similar [issue](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/98) submitted to `tkcalendar`.

Comment: @acw1668 yes that's almost the same issue. Thank you! it's weird, if you use first day Monday then it works fine.